# BigCommerce Stencil: How do I modify the HTML of a Theme already applied to the store?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm one of the Integration Team members at SearchSpring, a SaaS company who is partnered with BigCommerce.

Part of our integration process involves adding scripts to specific pages within the BigCommerce Theme (search.html, category.html, brands.html)

As an outside party, on Blueprint Themes, we were able to easily make these changes within the Control Panel's Design Area. But, with BigCommerce Stencil Themes, that "Modify HTML" area is gone.

Question:

How (or when) will we be able download Stencil Themes already applied to the store to make HTML modifications?

Consider a customer who has purchased a custom Theme from the Template Marketplace. If they have no access to send us the theme's files, we as an outside party, currently can't do anything for them in terms of integrating our solution into the templates. Is that correct?

In the [What's Coming Soon](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/new-and-pending-features#Coming) section, I have read the following:

> Support is still pending for merchants' self-service downloading of
>   custom themes.

And I believe that's exactly what I'm looking for here. However, the [Release Notes](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/release-notes) page does not provide any insight to the development efforts of this feature.

Is there a timeline or roadmap anywhere that will clue us into when this feature will be released? Even if an accurate ETA is not available at this time, a guess-timate of days, weeks, or months would also be helpful.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a public facing ETA or timeline that can be provided. It is something being worked on and that we (BigCommerce) knows is highly desired. We are even working on a way to help facilitate app partners in a more straightforward fashion. Your internal point of contact at BC might have more leeway to divulge.

As anyone who has purchased from the Stencil theme marketplace today cannot download their template files, it is correct that you have no way (today) of modifying the template to install SearchSpring.

Comment: WebDav is still going to be enabled as it is used to support/access different assets like product images. There will be a way to eventually download the theme files .

Comment: No, it isn't occurring through WebDav. Stencil is supported by different architecture.